# match the times and values in side the document, that will find min, avg, max from that document in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Explanation:** I want to find the `value_avg`, `time_avg` , `value_min`, `time_min`, `value_max`, `time_max`. In `time_values` we have objects, `time` and `value` field, first we have to `$match` the `time_values` with `data.time_start` and `data.time_end`.
second step could be in between time range, that will `$match`, we will find the `value_avg`, `time_avg` , `value_min`, `time_min`, `value_max`, `time_max` . please see the expected output.
In Expected output `remaining_time_values` will those elements that will `$match`.
If you have any questions let me know, please. Thanks in advance.

```
{
  "data": {
    "time_start": "2021-09-09T09:17:01.891Z",
    "time_end": "2021-09-09T09:17:11.091Z",
    "value_start": 142,
    "value_end": 1384
  },
  "time_values": [
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:01.491Z",
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:01.691Z",
      "value": 10
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:01.891Z",
      "value": 142
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:02.091Z",
      "value": 479
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:02.291Z",
      "value": 1166
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:02.491Z",
      "value": 1430
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:02.691Z",
      "value": 1089
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:02.891Z",
      "value": 759
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:03.091Z",
      "value": 896
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:03.291Z",
      "value": 1331
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:03.491Z",
      "value": 1384
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:11.091Z",
      "value": 1384
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:11.291Z",
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:21.095Z",
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:21.300Z",
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:23.695Z",
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:23.895Z",
      "value": 270
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:24.095Z",
      "value": 492
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:24.295Z",
      "value": 603
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:24.495Z",
      "value": 769
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:24.701Z",
      "value": 851
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:24.895Z",
      "value": 938
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:25.095Z",
      "value": 1120
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:25.299Z",
      "value": 1123
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:25.495Z",
      "value": 880
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:25.695Z",
      "value": 640
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:25.895Z",
      "value": 630
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:26.095Z",
      "value": 645
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:35.896Z",
      "value": 645
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:36.106Z",
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:49.097Z",
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:49.295Z",
      "value": 464
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:49.495Z",
      "value": 1154
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:49.695Z",
      "value": 1548
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:49.895Z",
      "value": 1479
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:50.095Z",
      "value": 1562
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:50.295Z",
      "value": 1731
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:50.496Z",
      "value": 1897
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:50.695Z",
      "value": 1976
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:50.895Z",
      "value": 1922
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:51.095Z",
      "value": 1721
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:51.296Z",
      "value": 1336
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:51.525Z",
      "value": 951
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:51.695Z",
      "value": 772
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:51.895Z",
      "value": 1008
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:52.095Z",
      "value": 1417
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:59.095Z",
      "value": 1417
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Output Document.

```
{
"data": {
  "time_start": "2021-09-09T09:17:01.891Z",
  "time_end": "2021-09-09T09:17:11.091Z",
  "value_start": 142,
  "value_end": 1384,
  "value_avg" :"??",
  "time_min" : "??",
  "value_min" : "??",
  "time_max" : "??",
  "value_max" : "??"
},
  "remaining_time_values": [
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:01.891Z",
      "value": 142
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:02.091Z",
      "value": 479
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:02.291Z",
      "value": 1166
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:02.491Z",
      "value": 1430
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:02.691Z",
      "value": 1089
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:02.891Z",
      "value": 759
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:03.091Z",
      "value": 896
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:03.291Z",
      "value": 1331
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:03.491Z",
      "value": 1384
    },
    {
      "time": "2021-09-09T09:17:11.091Z",
      "value": 1384
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I try to do the `$match`  but It was not helpfull. did you get the question and have an idea ?

Comment: Did you check the documentation? [Accumulators (in Other Stages)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#accumulators--in-other-stages-)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes dear I check it, But I don't exactly how I can build the query on that base logically. I know these Accumulators.

Comment: do you know how I can build the query base on that structure?

Comment: There are different approached you can try - this is one.  Matching doesn't happen on the array elements using the `$match` stage; first do an `$unwind` on the array field and _then_ do the match (a date range query). On this filtered data, do a grouping (`$group`) and your average, max, min, etc. Refer the manual for the respective aggregation stages and  operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an aggregation query like this:

- First `$unwind` to deconstruct the array and operate for each value.
- I have used `$set` to parse string to Date, but if your data is yet a Date object is not necessary this step.
- Then `$match` to compare between desired range (I think this is the match you want but if you want to use `$gt` or `$lt` instead of `$gte` and `$lte` you can change this.
- And `$group` to reconstruct the array using accumulation operators like `$avg`, `$max` and `$min` to get desired values.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$time_values"
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "data.time_start": {
        "$toDate": "$data.time_start"
      },
      "data.time_end": {
        "$toDate": "$data.time_end"
      },
      "time_values.time": {
        "$toDate": "$time_values.time"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$and": [
          {
            "$lte": [
              "$data.time_start",
              "$time_values.time"
            ]
          },
          {
            "$gte": [
              "$data.time_end",
              "$time_values.time"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "time_start": {
        "$first": "$data.time_start"
      },
      "time_end": {
        "$first": "$data.time_end"
      },
      "value_start": {
        "$first": "$data.value_start"
      },
      "value_end": {
        "$first": "$data.value_end"
      },
      "remaining_time_values": {
        "$push": "$time_values"
      },
      "value_avg": {
        "$avg": "$time_values.value"
      },
      "time_min": {
        "$min": "$time_values.time"
      },
      "value_min": {
        "$min": "$time_values.value"
      },
      "time_max": {
        "$max": "$time_values.time"
      },
      "value_max": {
        "$max": "$time_values.value"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yGeg4bWQh4H)

Comment: is it possible we can do without `unwind` because I have 10K+ documents? It's a very expensive performance point of view.

Comment: You missed `{$sort: {"time_values.time": 1}}`, otherwise `$first: ...` is not determined.

Comment: You could run without `$unwind` and `$group`, provided the data in `time_values` is already sorted. 10k documents should be no problem though.

Comment: `$first` is used only on `data`  object which will be the same because is grouping by `$_id`, or I'm missing something? @WernfriedDomscheit. Also without `$unwind` I think you can use `$filter` like  [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tO1Gtl-8ISQ). If date time is also a `Date` object you can avoid first `$set`.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. `value_start` and `value_end` was already available from source.

Comment: Thank you for your Participation!